# Stop nginx in django completely

Tags: django, nginx

I have used nginx as web server for django project , And now i want to use my normal django local server (switch to older local server).

I tried

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

(It is showing nginx is stopped)
i killed all process too.
But still my localserver:127.0.0.1:8000 is under nginx control.And my computer ip is also under nginx control.(it shows the nginx default page)

I want free that particular port(localserver:127.0.0.1:8000). How can i completely stop nginx ?

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop`?

Comment: I have tried that one also,But it wasn't working

Comment: Nginx doesn't run a django server. Typically something like supervisor or a similar service will, nginx just takes that server running on gunicorn or something and forwards it through nginx. You most likely need to do a sudo service supervisor stop, but be careful that you aren't shutting down other services that you may be using supervisor for

Comment: @MattCamilli is on target.  Nginx doesn't (normally) run on port 8000, your wsgi container does.  Look for `supervisor`, `uwsgi`, `unicorn`, `tornado` or other wsgi containers that are keeping that port.  Also, check for fast-cgi processes as an alternative.